# If select option value matches variable value

Tags: jquery, text, filter, attributes, attr

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/hKqU6/1/

To put things simply, I'm trying to get the value of the variable `linkPath`.

This is what I'm trying to achieve with the above code:

When a user selects an option from the select box, look at it's text (e.g. Purple) and then select the `.thumbnails a` tag which contains that text in it's title attribute.

Provided that is successful, alert that specific `.thumbnails a` tag's href.

Can anybody help me achieve this? Pretty sure it's possible and I feel like I'm close...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pycc9/

Comment: Thank you all for the quick, clear response! I knew it would be something simple like that. Although I don't really understand why concatenation is required in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate that variable into the selector:

```
var linkPath = $('.thumbnails > a[title*=' + selectVal + ']').attr('href');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hKqU6/3/

Answer (score 0):

The `selectVal` should be concatinated:

```
var linkPath = $('.thumbnails > a[title*='+selectVal+']').attr('href');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKqU6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below JS code:

```
$(".variations select").on("change", function() {
    var selectVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var linkPath = $('.thumbnails > a[title*='+selectVal+']').attr('href');
    alert(linkPath);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
var linkPath = $('.thumbnails > a[title*='+selectVal+']').attr('href');
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hKqU6/6/).